Coolify with CloudFlared & SSL/TLS HTTPS
I want to use Coolify with CloudFlare Tunnels, so all my apps will be public using https domains, e.g. https://test.mydomain.com
I followed the steps mentioned in docs in order to have a tunnel & a wildcard subdomain,
except that instead of http://localhost:80 I used http://coolify-proxy:80 (my CF tunnel public endpoint), because that's the only way it's working, as I found here
Then, in Coolify I created a new resource
services:
  cloudflared:
    container_name: cloudflare-tunnel
    image: 'cloudflare/cloudflared:latest'
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: 'tunnel --no-autoupdate run'
    environment:
      - 'TUNNEL_TOKEN=${CLOUDFLARE_TUNNEL_TOKEN}'
    networks:
      - coolify
networks:
  coolify:
    external: true

Then, on my CloudFlare domain -> SSL/TLS -> I've set the encryption mode to Full; I also tried with Full (strict)
Then, for each resource created, if I set a domain like http://test.mydomain.com, it works, except that for the https version http://test.mydomain.com I get This site can’t be reached.
Why isn't the https working?
PS: if I add the https from coolify settings for each resource, both version won't be reached.

Update: it worked actually, but for some reason my Brave browser, even if I used incognito, cached the 'can't be reached' response forever. It worked using other browser :)
Full solution here - https://discord.com/channels/459365938081431553/1316486632714539061
